# Microsoft.Identity.Web and ASP.NET Core SignalR JWT authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using ASP.NET Core to make a web application that also uses SignalR Core to provide real time functionality. I use Azure AD B2C for user management. I have successfully used `Microsoft.Identity.Web` (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web) to secure my API endpoints using tokens generated by Azure AD B2C.

I would like to do the same for my SignalR Core hubs. The documentation reads to add the appropriate annotation to your hubs/methods, which I have done. SignalR's client side library adds the access token as a query parameter which must be extracted and added to the context manually in the configuration of your ASP.NET core application, like so.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                // If the request is for our hub...
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                    (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/chat")))
                {
                    // Read the token out of the query string
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

However, this seems to be incompatible with the configuration supplied by `Microsoft.Identity.Web`, here:

```
        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

How can I make SignalR work with `Microsoft.Identity.Web`?

Comment: Jesse, I'm completely confused with what you are trying to achieve. This is bypassing Microsoft.Identity.Web. Why do you need the access token arriving to your web API? 

Do you have a link on the documentation you mention? I'd like to have a look at it (and maybe have it updated ?)

if you are using MIcrosoft.Identity.Web, just use IDownstreamWebApi, GraphServiceClient or, ITokenAcquisition in your controller action?

Comment: Have you seen this documentation?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bearer-token-authentication

Answer (score 9):

That should do it:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration);

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    Func<MessageReceivedContext, Task> existingOnMessageReceivedHandler = options.Events.OnMessageReceived;
    options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context =>
    {
      await existingOnMessageReceivedHandler(context);

      StringValues accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
      PathString path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

      // If the request is for our hub...
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"))
      {
        // Read the token out of the query string
        context.Token = accessToken;
      }
    };
});
```

Instead of adding a JwtBearer, you can configure the JwtBearerOptions object this way.

Adapted from this documentation: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/customization

Comment: Might not be ideal but it does the trick perfectly, should be accepted

Comment: Oh my... Nearly a year later this answer has helped me a lot, saving me from wasting another week trying to figure that out, thank you! I did not know whether my front-end or back-end side was faulty, and it turned out that your solution works perfectly fine but for me it actually worked after some front-end tweaking. I've used it with Angular 13 and the "@azure/msal-angular" library, for those interested.

Comment: This just got me working with Angular 17 and the msal library as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio to set up the SignalR connection, and then just add this line in startup.cs (VS might add it automatically)

```cs
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
```

[This dev sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/tree/master/tests/BlazorServerCallsGraph) has SignalR set up, just the connection string is missing, but might give you an idea of what to do. Most of this was done automatically with VS. If you have issues setting it up, please open an issue in the [repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/). thanks.

Comment: Note that the AddAzureSignalR  is for "Azure" SignlarR. (and correct link to sample : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/tree/master/tests/DevApps/BlazorServerCallsGraph