# AzureAd JwtBearer No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am trying to modify my AzureAd authentication to work with SignalR. So I have changed the authentication so I can add further options.

Before I had `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");` which worked fine.

According to this [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#:~:text=you%20can%20also%20write%20the%20following%20(which%20is%20equivalent)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#:%7E:text=you%20can%20also%20write%20the%20following%20(which%20is%20equivalent))
I should be able to use `services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme) .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");`

But instead I get a `System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).` When hitting my API.

Comment: You need this in startup.cs: services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found with default authentification and custom authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324129/no-authenticationscheme-was-specified-and-there-was-no-defaultchallengescheme-f)

Answer (score 0):

> Error :System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was
> specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default
> schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string
> defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action
> configureOptions).

While sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform([refer](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis#protected-web-apis---startupcs)) ,
Add the Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet packages

According to error try with adding default scheme by checking below  ways :

In startup class under configure services method

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(
           options => {  Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

                //options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
             
                  //

                   //custom code
}
```

OR

```js
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   
services .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 

         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 

    options => {
 
      options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = async failedContext => {

 if (failedContext.Exception.HResult == -2147024891) 
{ 
    failedContext.Response.StatusCode = 403; 

    await failedContext.Response.CompleteAsync(); 

  } 
           };

              });
//
//
}
```

(or)

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
               //
         services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
          {
         sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    
         
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    
        })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(
               options =>
               {
               //
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    //options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                   
                   //
                   
     
               //custom code
          }
    
         }
```

And also make sure you have this line of cod app.UseAuthentication(); in your Configure() method on top of app.UseAuthorization() if present.

Also check [this](https://rasmustherkelsen.wordpress.com/2021/02/04/migrate-your-secure-asp-net-core-3-1-applications-to-asp-net-core-5s-microsoft-identity-web/)

**References:**

1. [Azure-Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph)
2. [microsoft-identity-web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/customization)
3. [SO ref-signalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209097/microsoft-identity-web-and-asp-net-core-signalr-jwt-authentication)